# Same generic type in two different classes in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have two different classes:

```
class A<K,V> {
  B b = new B;

  public V get(K k) {
     return b.get(k);
  }
}

class B<K,V> {
  V v;

  public V get(K k) {
     return v;
  }
}
```

I get an incompatible types error in the get method of class A.

Does that mean type V of class A is not the same as type V of class B?
In that case, how do I fix this issue?
Can I simply typecast it to V before returning?

Answer (score 2):

Parametrize `B` with `V` in `A`. This way the compiler can be sure that your class `B` will return an object of type `V`.

```
class A<K,V> {
  B<K,V> b = new B<K,V>;

  public V get(K k) {
     return b.get(k);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank Neil. I saw David's answer below first and had a follow up question there. Would you happen to know the answer to that one?

Answer (score 2):

Change  `B b = new B;` inside class `A`  to `B<K,V> b = new B<>();`

This makes sure that the types referenced by `K` and `V` within the definition of `B` for the variable `b` match up with those within the definition of `A`.

Comment: Thanks David! That helped. Just a follow up. If instead of B b, I was creating an array B[] b, I wouldn't be able to use B<K V>[] b. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: As far as I know, Concrete parametrized types are not permitted for arrays. You could use a raw type B[] b or else use a Collection.